# Swift cannot read http response header from asp.net web service

Tags: swift, web-services, iis, http-headers, httpresponse

I moved my ASP.net web API webservice to a new IIS 10 server
on a new server, and my IOS Application can't read HTTP Response Header.

The Header is `Token`

From Postman I notice the following header:
`Access-Control-Expose-Headers →Token,TokenExpiry`

it's working on Android

I tried to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` - it didn't work
any suggestions ?

Comment: Hmm even after cleaning up your question, I don't understand what the problem is on iOS, what worked on Android, and what did you try to do. Clearer details, and some code please

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers Try to allow your custom headers first.

Comment: If you want to use Access-Control-Allow-Origin on IIS, you need to install [CORS.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference) Another thing is that iOS safari doesn't support [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers#browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

I had  disable HTTP2 from server and all worked ,
HTTP2 return custom response header small letter , that's why  swift couldn't find the headers  .